# Fancybox opens twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I have div with fancybox call

Here is code of it

```
 <div class="name"><%= popup_ajax hotel.name, hotel_info_path(hotel) %></div>
```

It opens fancybox

Here is how it looks like after compilation

```
<div class="name"><a class=" fancybox" data-type="ajax" data-src="/hotel_info/72721" data-options="{&quot;touch&quot;:false,&quot;baseClass&quot;:null}" href="javascript:;">Ibis London Thurrock M25</a></div>
```

I need to open it and show map in div by clicking on  `<div class="name">`

I was able to make it like this

```
$(".name").click(function(){
     $.fancybox.open($("a.fancybox"),{
      afterLoad: function(){
       lat = $(".hotel_info").data('hotel-lat');
       lng = $(".hotel_info").data('hotel-lng');
        myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(lng,lat);
        mapboxgl.accessToken = token;
        let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
           container: 'map-canvas-info',
           style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
           center: myLatlng,
           zoom: 14
     });
     map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
     let marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
     .setLngLat(myLatlng)
     .addTo(map);
    }
    });
});
```

But it opens fancybox twice. How I can fix this?

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I cant, because there is ruby syntax in View@ChrisG

Comment: Yes you can, just use fixed example data. This is about fancybox opening twice, not map data.

Comment: https://codepen.io/suhomlineugene/pen/zawPVq

Here is it, but in fiddle all, ok. @ChrisG

Comment: Alright, replication unsuccessful. Not sure what we can do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating anchor element anyway? Something like this would be much simpler -

HTML

```
<div class="name">Ibis London Thurrock M25</div>
```

JS

```
$(".name").click(function(){
  $.fancybox.open({
    src  : 'https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/oBgoqB.html',
    type : 'ajax',
    opts : {
      touch : false,
      afterLoad: function(){
        alert("Opened");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

DEMO
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVRJdE?editors=1010